# Intellisense not working for flutter plugin project in android studio

Tags: flutter, android-studio, flutter-plugin, flutter-platform-channel

I am using android studio Artic-Fox 2020.3.1. I created a flutter plugin project using the android studio, intellisense is not working for the `android` module but it's working fine for `lib` module.

[image]

There is no compiler error or any suggestion. Nothing is working.

Flutter version : 2.5.1
Dart version 2.14.2

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: You are opening your project as a flutter project that's why you are not getting auto completion. Open flutter project's ANDROID module inside the android studio that will work.